# Using a string to find its integer value in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Hey i would like to make a list with:(the integer is the amount it costs)

```
Price=0
List=[('apple',1),('banana',2),('carrot',3)] 
Text=input('what do you want?')
Amount=int(input('how many do you want?'))
if Text=='apple':
    Price=List[int(0)]*Amount  
print(Price)
```

And be able to use one to find the other. What is this called(/how do you 
do this) because i tried to search for it and found nothing, might have 
been searching for the wrong thing thank you.

```
Price=0
List=[('apple',1),('banana',2),('carrot',3)]
Text=input('apple')
Amount=int(input('5'))
if Text=='apple':
    Price=1*5  
print(5)
```

i don't know if this is how you meant it @MayankPorwal

Comment: Can you please add some sample input and expected output so it is clearer for us?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is called a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: @glibdud isn't a dictionary only for one item?

Comment: @aronbleier See the examples in the documentation I linked.

Comment: thank you i really helped @glibdud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try using a dictionary for this. You can create the dict in a few different ways, but one way would be like `{'apple': 1}` where the dict key is the item and the value is the price. Then you can access the price based on user input using `dict[key]`. For example:

```
items = {'apple': 1, 'banana': 2, 'carrot': 3} 

item = input('what do you want?')
quantity = int(input('how many do you want?'))

if item in items:
    price = items[item] * quantity
    print(f'Item: {item} Quantity: {quantity} Price: {price}')
else:
    print('Item not found')

# OUTPUT for item input 'banana' and quantity input '2'
# Item: banana Quantity: 2 Price: 4
```

Also, try to avoid using names like "list" for your variables since `list()` is a built in python function.

Comment: yes thank you i didn't know you could use a dictionary like that

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary is a simple solution. If you want to only use list, you can keep track of items and prices in separate lists, given than the order of the items and prices are kept fixed, then use the index of input item to find its associated price.

```
items = ['apple', 'banana', 'carrot'] 
prices = [1, 2, 3]

item = input('what do you want?')
quantity = int(input('how many do you want?'))

if item in items:
    item_index = items.index(item)
    price = prices[item_index] * quantity
    print('Item: {} Quantity: {} Price: {}'.format(item, quantity, price))
else:
    print('Item not found')
```